# Fourier transform of a tempered distribution

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

anybody knows how to calculate the fourier transform of $e^{-ax}, a>0$ in the sense of tempered function. I manage to find out it is $ \delta $ (y+ia) but it does not seem right as the 'argument' should not complex.

Comment: The function $x\mapsto e^{-ax}$ doesn't define a tempered distribution. However, you're correct in the sense that if $\hat \varphi$ is smooth with compact support (in which case $\varphi$ will be an entire function), $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax}\hat \varphi(x)\,dx = 2\pi \varphi(ai)$.